# executeQuery PreparedStatement retuning null

Tags: java, sql-server

Well, i have a simple code that should execute a SQL SERVER query and return a result set, but i got the following error:

```
the execute query must return a resultset
```

See the code:

```
statement.executeQuery();
```

This executeQuery() execute a query that returns more than 100K rows, in SQL SERVER console everything works but in java NOT. I changed the query adding a "TOP 10" and executeQuery() works normally.

Exists some timeout in executeQuery() ? I need return a lot of rows, as i said.

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are usually a maximum limit on how many rows the database will return per query.

So what you will have to do is to repeat through the resultset and will have to make multiple calls to the database server.

> This setMaxRows method has no effect for dynamic scrollable cursors.
>   The application should use SELECT TOP N SQL syntax to limit the number
>   of rows returned from potentially large result sets.

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT TOP N SQL
```

For more read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378838(v=sql.110).aspx).

Another thing that you can try doing is split the query using a for loop and setting the `limit` dynamically. Then you can handle the `resultset` the way you want to.

Comment: I can't do it because this call is made inside a library (jasperreports-3.7.6). In the class JRJdbcQueryExecuter

Comment: I know that i can solve that with "TOP N", but i need get all rows without limitation. is not possible ?

Comment: @Scientist I am afraid it might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using EXCEPT statement (for example):

```
(SELECT * FROM table_name) EXCEPT (SELECT TOP M FROM table_name)
```

You'll need to compute the value of M in each iteration of a for loop.
M can be for example:

M = N / 2, N / 4, 3 * N / 4, etc...

And you can get the value of N using the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
```